# How to move a control in a form with by keyboard?

Tags: c#

How can I move a control ( a image ) in the form by keyboard?
I don't know how to do it.
C#
Thanks

Comment: Handle the key press event and move if it's arrow key

Comment: ok good, I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use WinForm (but for WPF its not much different):
Each control has a [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event, which is fired when a key is pressed down (and a KeyUP and KeyPress which are fired accordingly:

So you can do something like the following (e.g. in the constructor or load event of the form):

```
//this enables the form to receive all key events if a child control has focus
this.KeyPreview = true; 

this.KeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        picture.Location.Y++;
    //etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean moving objects in design mode, it's impossible, because positioning of elements on form should be done via CSS.